Laravel convert empty object to empty array
When I send an empty object to my Laravel API, it converts it into an empty array. This is a problem because I want to store this empty object as it is in my database.
Here is the body I send :
{
    "shouldBeEmptyArray": [],
    "shouldBeEmptyObject": {},
}

and here is the response I get if I just return the request content in my controller :
[
    [],
    []
]

If think this has something to do with the json() method inside Request.php, which use true value for the associative parameter of json_decode(), but I can't find a way to make it work the way I want (and I don't really want to change this file because it's not a file of my project. I tried to override the method in my own Request custom class by extending Request but I doesn't work). Here is the code of the json() method of Request.php :
    /**
     * Get the JSON payload for the request.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $key
     * @param  mixed  $default
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag|mixed
     */
    public function json($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        if (! isset($this->json)) {
            $this->json = new InputBag((array) json_decode($this->getContent(), true));
        }

        if (is_null($key)) {
            return $this->json;
        }

        return data_get($this->json->all(), $key, $default);
    }

and here is how I tried to override it :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag;

class RequestJsonOverride extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public function json($key = null, $default = null)
    {
        if (! isset($this->json)) {
            $this->json = new InputBag((array) json_decode($this->getContent(), false));
        }

        if (is_null($key)) {
            return $this->json;
        }

        return data_get($this->json->all(), $key, $default);
    }
}


So you know the solution in terms of json_decode, but you couldn't override the standard functionality, is that right? So It think your real question is how to override this function without changing the base code?

My real question is "is it a good idea to override like this and if yes, how to do it the good way". By asking this question, I hope someone know another way to do it by not overriding this method (maybe there is some configuration flag that does exactly this but that I can't find)

well, since there's nothing you can pass into the function which would change the json_decode behaviour, and nothing within the function which tries to control it based on reading a config value, I'd guess it's probably not controllable by config, unless there's some config which can tell the system to run an entirely different function instead for this process.

Ok so maybe I should dig the idea of overrinding the method. I'll add the code of my custom request to my original answer, maybe you will see what I'm doing wrong

Or maybe I could use a middleware to do this, but are middlewares called too late, after the request has already been transformed (if it's the case, I can't do that bc the information about if it's an array or an object is already lost)

Well, I tried the middleware and it seems like it's too late at this stage...

"I want to store this empty object as it is in my database" Not clear what it means. Are you storing the JSON itself in a table?

What I showed is a simplified version of what's happening in my application. The real scenario is that the front-end is sending me a bunch of information, one of  which is a big JSON. In this json, some field are empty object and I want them to keep being empty object to store it, so when I sendthe big JSON back to my front-end, it's the same as what it sent me before

If you want exactly the input JSON, then it's just $request->getContent().

Oh... yes, you're right. I thought the original content was erased when it became a request object. So yes, I just have to do json_decode($request->getContent(), false). Thank you

Can you please post your comment as an answer so I can validate it
